# In google chrome auto click button

Tags: javascript, automation

Anyone know how to change the action of a certain button to auto click infinitely.
Is it possible to execute in google chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have this button:

```
<button id="infiniteButton"></button>
```

You can make it clicking every minute (60000 ms) using jQuery this way:

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        $('#infiniteButton').click();
      }, 60000)
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

`setInterval()` method calls a function at some interval.